# Remove unnecessary strings and special characters using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have this string:

```bsh
$html = @'
<div><span style="display:inline !important;">As an Inventory and OperationsAgent</span></div><div><span style="display:inline !important;">I want to be able to raise internal EPL Nominations for Buildings that are going through a Shared Installation journey</span></div><div><span style="display:inline !important;">So that internal EPLNominations can be submitted when the TDF cost is too expensive for both P2P and Shared</span></div>
'@
```

... how do I remove all the HTML tags?

Comment: I need <div><span style="display:inline !important;">As an Inventory and OperationsAgent</span></div><div><span style="display:inline !important;">I want to be able to raise internal EPL Nominations for Buildings that are going through a Shared Installation journey</span></div><div><span style="display:inline !important;">So that internal EPLNominations can be submitted when the TDF cost is too expensive for both P2P and Shared</span></div>"

Comment: i need to remove <div><span style="display:inline !important;"> these type of strings and special characters.

Comment: i need only like :  As an Inventory and OperationsAgent, I want to be able to raise internal EPL Nominations for Buildings that are going through a Shared Installation journey.

Comment: can u help me to resolve this issue asap possible.

Comment: I've re-formatted your question, please review that it's indeed what you wanted to ask. If not, please [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64787590/edit) instead of using comments :)

Comment: using powershell i need to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-replace` regex operator to remove all the html tags:

```bsh
$html -replace '<[^>]+>'
```

To substitute `,`  for the `<div>` boundaries as well:

```bsh
$html -replace '</div>\s*<div>',', ' -replace '<[^>]+>'
```

Which will output a string like:

> As an Inventory and OperationsAgent, I want to be able to raise internal EPL Nominations for Buildings that are going through a Shared Installation journey, So that internal EPLNominations can be submitted when the TDF cost is too expensive for both P2P and Shared

Comment: using your command i am unable to delete fully.
<steps id="0" last="4"><step id="2" type="ValidateStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Login to CRM&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;User should be able to login to CRM&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step><step id="3" type="ValidateStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">

Comment: &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Login to CRM&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;User should be able to log
in to CRM&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Go to Order Product and open any existing record&lt;/P&gt;&lt
;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;User should be able to open existing record&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&
gt;Set "Ready for Payment" as yes and set either invoice received or invoice requested flag  to Yes on Order Product form&l
t;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Error message should not be displayed and user should be able to

Comment: I need to remove these things also
&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;
 can you please help me on that

Comment: @MohammadHafiz Update your question then, it doesn't say anything about doubly-encoded HTML

Comment: separate question need to ask?

Comment: can you help me on the above issue. how to remove  &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt. 
i am unable to remove these  &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt using $html -replace '</div>\s*<div>',', ' -replace '<[^>]+>'

Answer (score 0):

You can decode your html first and then replace the html tags:

```
$DecodedHtml = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::htmldecode($html)
$DecodedHtml -replace '<[^>]*>'
```